# How to show error message below input field in blade file - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation, frameworks

I am validating input using rules in laravel, Currently, I am using the below code to show errors in my view if validation fails.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The problem with the above code is all the errors are coming in one place. How can I show errors below their respective inputs (Like Name, Email, Password, etc). And where can I define my custom error messages? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.8.13, you can use the `@error` blade directive. Just place your desired error markup below your input field:

```
@error('field-name')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

If there was an error validating `field-name`, the message related to the error will be displayed.

As for customising your validation error messages, check the Laravel documentation on [Custom Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-error-messages) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that for every field

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" 
            name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" autofocus>
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                <span class="invalid feedback"role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}.</strong>
                </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possibile display in some way error outside form tag?